# Is it true that x(t)*\delta(t-nT) is nonzero iff n=t/T?

Tags: integration, functions

[image: Calculation]
Note: T is just some constant and n is an integer.
I'm trying to verify the steps.But I'm unsure that the statement is true since for n=5, the expression would be nonzero at 5T (assuming x(5) is non-zero).